# This problem was encountered in Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried almost every way to fix it but I failed please help.

```
  Execution failed for task `':app :process Debug Google Services'.`
    > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot 
    function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\AYAT\Menu2\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\AYAT\Menu2\app\src\google-services.json
  C:\Users\AYAT\Menu2\app\google-services.json
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you want. Is the google-services.json file missing?

Comment: Please be more concise with your question. I can't tell what exactly your issue is. Provide a minimal, reproducible example and add it to your question